# Error en ejecución proyecto Angular2

Tags: angularjs-2.0

Estoy tratando de correr un proyecto de Angular2 pero al ejecutar el comando 'ng serve' me aparece el siguiente error...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No se ve la imagen con la captura del error, con lo cual tampoco se entiende la pregunta. Por favor, agregar la imagen nuevamente o copiar el mensaje de error.

Comment: Hola. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Creo que una pregunta de este estilo, si bien es totalmente válida, _debería_ dar un poco más de información a quien quiera ayudarte (ayúdanos a ayudarte). Para alguien que no está en tu lugar, la pregunta da muy poco contexto; no explica qué se está haciendo ni de dónde salió esta imagen, ni por qué estás interesado en entenderlo, ni nada que nos de alguna pista del objetivo. Te recomiendo [edit] la pregunta agregando algo más de información, y sería bueno que realices el [tour] y leer [ask]. La idea es ofrecer un __[mcve]__ en todas las preguntas.

Answer (score 1):

Debes añadir las siguientes exclusiones al proyecto

```
"exclude": [ 
    "typings/browser",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/browser.d.ts",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
```

Otras soluciones posibles, puedes encontrarlas en el foro de microsoft, donde fue reportado el issue.

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7369

Comment: Gracias. Lo solucioné ejecutando los siguientes comandos:

sudo npm uninstall typings -g
sudo npm install typings@0.8.1 -g
typings install

Era un problema con la versión de typings